# Filling in missing dates with values from the month before

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_data (label text, value integer, date date);
INSERT INTO my_data (label, value, date) VALUES 
('AAA', 10, '2014-06-01'),
('AAA', 30, '2014-09-01'),
('AAA', 40, '2014-10-01'),
('AAA', 50, '2015-02-01'),
('BBB', 20, '2014-11-01'),
('BBB', 10, '2015-02-01'),
('BBB', 70, '2015-04-01');
```

and I need to fill up the missing dates (imagine a time series) in this way:

```
label | value | date
------+-------+------------
AAA   | 10    | 2014-06-01
AAA   | 10    | 2014-07-01
AAA   | 10    | 2014-08-01
AAA   | 30    | 2014-09-01
AAA   | 40    | 2014-10-01
AAA   | 40    | 2014-11-01
AAA   | 40    | 2014-12-01
AAA   | 40    | 2015-01-01
AAA   | 50    | 2015-02-01
AAA   | 50    | 2015-03-01
AAA   | 50    | 2015-04-01
BBB   | 20    | 2014-11-01
BBB   | 20    | 2014-12-01
BBB   | 20    | 2015-01-01
BBB   | 10    | 2015-02-01
BBB   | 10    | 2015-03-01
BBB   | 70    | 2015-04-01
```

where the time range goes from '2014-06-01' to '2015-04-01'.
What I did so far is:

```
WITH 
md AS
(
SELECT *, LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY label ORDER BY date) AS next_date FROM my_data
),
calendar AS
(
select date::date from generate_series('2014-06-01'::date, '2015-04-01'::date, '1 month'::interval) date
)
SELECT m.label, m.value, c.date
FROM calendar c
JOIN md m
    ON c.date BETWEEN m.date AND (m.next_date - interval '1 month') order by label, date;
 label | value |    date    
-------+-------+------------
 AAA   |    10 | 2014-06-01
 AAA   |    10 | 2014-07-01
 AAA   |    10 | 2014-08-01
 AAA   |    30 | 2014-09-01
 AAA   |    40 | 2014-10-01
 AAA   |    40 | 2014-11-01
 AAA   |    40 | 2014-12-01
 AAA   |    40 | 2015-01-01
 BBB   |    20 | 2014-11-01
 BBB   |    20 | 2014-12-01
 BBB   |    20 | 2015-01-01
 BBB   |    10 | 2015-02-01
 BBB   |    10 | 2015-03-01
(13 rows)
```

The returned values of the query do not fill up the whole time range (until 2015-04). How can I make the query work in that way?

**UPDATE**

I think I have fixed it:

```
WITH 
md AS
(
SELECT *, LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY label ORDER BY date) AS next_date FROM my_data
),
calendar AS
(
select date::date from generate_series('2014-06-01'::date, '2015-04-01'::date, '1 month'::interval) date
)
SELECT m.label, m.value, c.date
FROM calendar c
JOIN md m
    ON c.date BETWEEN m.date AND 
    (CASE WHEN m.next_date IS NULL THEN date '2015-04-01' ELSE m.next_date - interval '1 month' END) order by label, date;
```

Answer (score 4):

First it generates a series of date by label and then you can use either a lateral join:

> ```
> with a as
> (
>     select   label, generate_series(min(date), '2015-04-01'::date, interval '1 month') dt
>     from     my_data
>     group by label
> )
> select    label,
>           t1.value,
>            dt
> from      a
> left join lateral (select t1.value
>                    from   my_data t1
>                    where  t1.label = a.label
>                    and    t1.date <= a.dt
>                    order by label, date desc
>                    limit 1) t1 on true
> order by  label, dt
> ```

or a subquery:

> ```
> with a as
> (
>     select   label, generate_series(min(date), '2015-04-01'::date, interval '1 month') dt
>     from     my_data
>     group by label
> )
> select    label,
>           (select t1.value
>            from   my_data t1
>            where  t1.label = a.label
>            and    t1.date <= a.dt
>            order by label, date desc
>            limit 1),
>            dt
> from      a
> order by  label, dt
> ```
>
> ```
> label | value | dt                    
> :---- | ----: | :---------------------
> AAA   |    10 | 2014-06-01 00:00:00+01
> AAA   |    10 | 2014-07-01 00:00:00+01
> AAA   |    10 | 2014-08-01 00:00:00+01
> AAA   |    30 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00+01
> AAA   |    40 | 2014-10-01 00:00:00+01
> AAA   |    40 | 2014-11-01 00:00:00+00
> AAA   |    40 | 2014-12-01 00:00:00+00
> AAA   |    40 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00+00
> AAA   |    50 | 2015-02-01 00:00:00+00
> AAA   |    50 | 2015-03-01 00:00:00+00
> AAA   |    50 | 2015-04-01 00:00:00+01
> BBB   |    20 | 2014-11-01 00:00:00+00
> BBB   |    20 | 2014-12-01 00:00:00+00
> BBB   |    20 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00+00
> BBB   |    10 | 2015-02-01 00:00:00+00
> BBB   |    10 | 2015-03-01 00:00:00+00
> BBB   |    70 | 2015-04-01 00:00:00+01
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2b6d67bdb40bb2090c5f938445e5082d)*

Comment: I tried to use it with an original table of ~100,000 values and it is very slow. Maybe a solution with a 'window function' could be better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very conservative query, you can optimize some of the stuff out if you want -- like the conservative date-join that you may not require.

```
SELECT label, mo::date, first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY label, mo) AS value
FROM (
  SELECT t2.label, gs.mo, m.value, sum((m.value>0)::int) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.label ORDER BY mo) AS grp
  FROM (SELECT max(date) FROM my_data) AS t1
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT label, min(date) FROM my_data GROUP BY label) AS t2
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(
    t2.min::timestamp without time zone,
    t1.max::timestamp without time zone,
    '1 month'
  ) AS gs(mo)
  LEFT JOIN my_data AS m
    ON m.label = t2.label
    AND date_trunc('month', gs.mo) = date_trunc('month', m.date)
) AS t
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Let's dissect this. First we need to generate the date range.

```
SELECT t2.label, gs.mo
FROM (SELECT max(date) FROM my_data) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT label, min(date) FROM my_data GROUP BY label) AS t2
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(
  t2.min::timestamp without time zone,
  t1.max::timestamp without time zone,
  '1 month'
) AS gs(mo);
 label |           mo           
-------+------------------------
 AAA   | 2014-06-01 00:00:00-05
 AAA   | 2014-07-01 00:00:00-05
 AAA   | 2014-08-01 00:00:00-05
 AAA   | 2014-09-01 00:00:00-05
 AAA   | 2014-10-01 00:00:00-05
 AAA   | 2014-11-01 00:00:00-05
 AAA   | 2014-12-01 00:00:00-06
 AAA   | 2015-01-01 00:00:00-06
 AAA   | 2015-02-01 00:00:00-06
 AAA   | 2015-03-01 00:00:00-06
 AAA   | 2015-04-01 00:00:00-05
 BBB   | 2014-11-01 00:00:00-05
 BBB   | 2014-12-01 00:00:00-06
 BBB   | 2015-01-01 00:00:00-06
 BBB   | 2015-02-01 00:00:00-06
 BBB   | 2015-03-01 00:00:00-06
 BBB   | 2015-04-01 00:00:00-05
(17 rows)
```

Now, we're going to join that range back to the data set..

```
SELECT t2.label, gs.mo, m.value, sum((m.value>1)::int) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.label ORDER BY mo) AS grp
FROM (SELECT max(date) FROM my_data) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT label, min(date) FROM my_data GROUP BY label) AS t2
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(
  t2.min::timestamp without time zone,
  t1.max::timestamp without time zone,
  '1 month'
) AS gs(mo)
LEFT JOIN my_data AS m
  ON m.label = t2.label
  AND date_trunc('month', gs.mo) = date_trunc('month', m.date);
 label |           mo           | value | grp 
-------+------------------------+-------+-----
 AAA   | 2014-06-01 00:00:00-05 |    10 |   1
 AAA   | 2014-07-01 00:00:00-05 |       |   1
 AAA   | 2014-08-01 00:00:00-05 |       |   1
 AAA   | 2014-09-01 00:00:00-05 |    30 |   2
 AAA   | 2014-10-01 00:00:00-05 |    40 |   3
 AAA   | 2014-11-01 00:00:00-05 |       |   3
 AAA   | 2014-12-01 00:00:00-06 |       |   3
 AAA   | 2015-01-01 00:00:00-06 |       |   3
 AAA   | 2015-02-01 00:00:00-06 |    50 |   4
 AAA   | 2015-03-01 00:00:00-06 |       |   4
 AAA   | 2015-04-01 00:00:00-05 |       |   4
 BBB   | 2014-11-01 00:00:00-05 |    20 |   1
 BBB   | 2014-12-01 00:00:00-06 |       |   1
 BBB   | 2015-01-01 00:00:00-06 |       |   1
 BBB   | 2015-02-01 00:00:00-06 |    10 |   2
 BBB   | 2015-03-01 00:00:00-06 |       |   2
 BBB   | 2015-04-01 00:00:00-05 |    70 |   3
(17 rows)
```

A little trick there with `sum((m.value>0)::int) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.label ORDER BY mo)`. This

1. creates a bool out of the expression `m.value>0`
2. casts the bool to an int (where 1 results if the value is >0)
3. creates a running total with that by counting them.

Now all we have to do is retrieve the first value in that `grp`. So we wrap the whole thing in another select which produces

```
 label |     mo     | value 
-------+------------+-------
 AAA   | 2014-06-01 |    10
 AAA   | 2014-07-01 |    10
 AAA   | 2014-08-01 |    10
 AAA   | 2014-09-01 |    30
 AAA   | 2014-10-01 |    40
 AAA   | 2014-11-01 |    40
 AAA   | 2014-12-01 |    40
 AAA   | 2015-01-01 |    40
 AAA   | 2015-02-01 |    50
 AAA   | 2015-03-01 |    50
 AAA   | 2015-04-01 |    50
 BBB   | 2014-11-01 |    10
 BBB   | 2014-12-01 |    10
 BBB   | 2015-01-01 |    10
 BBB   | 2015-02-01 |    30
 BBB   | 2015-03-01 |    30
 BBB   | 2015-04-01 |    40
(17 rows)
```

See also, [How do I generate a date series in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/175963/2639) for more information about why we use *`timestamp without time zone`*.