# Fill missing dates within groups

Tags: postgresql, join, date, set-returning-functions

I have the following table with values for different stations from `2014-01-01` to `2014-01-04`. The data has some date gaps that I want to fill leaving the `value` as `NULL`, and assigning the missing date to each station. I'm working with PostgreSQL 10.9

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE stations (station_id text, value integer, date date);
INSERT INTO stations (station_id, value, date) VALUES 
('001', 10, '2014-01-01'),
('001', 30, '2014-01-03'),
('002', 40, '2014-01-01'),
('002', 50, '2015-01-02'),
('003', 20, '2014-01-01'),
('003', 10, '2015-01-02'),
('003', 70, '2015-01-04');
```

I also have a table holding unique stations with identifiers.

And I want something like this:

```
| station | value | date       |
|---------|-------|------------|
| 001     | 10    | 2014-01-01 |
| 001     | NULL  | 2014-01-02 |
| 001     | 30    | 2014-01-03 |
| 001     | NULL  | 2014-01-04 |
| 002     | 40    | 2014-01-01 |
| 002     | 50    | 2014-01-02 |
| 002     | NULL  | 2014-01-03 |
| 002     | NULL  | 2014-01-04 |
| 003     | 20    | 2014-01-01 |
| 003     | 10    | 2014-01-02 |
| 003     | NULL  | 2014-01-03 |
| 003     | 70    | 2014-01-04 |
```

Following some DBA Exchange (questions)[1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175949/filling-in-missing-dates-with-values-from-the-month-before), I tried a combination of a `LEFT JOIN` with a `LATERAL JOIN`:

```sql
WITH complete_dates_station AS (
    select station_id,
           generate_series(DATE '2014-01-01', DATE '2014-12-31', INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE as dt
    FROM stations
    GROUP by station_id
    ), temp_join AS (
        SELECT station_id,
               dt,
               s.value
        FROM complete_dates_station
            LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
                SELECT s.value
                FROM stations s
                WHERE s.station_id = complete_dates_station.station_id
                AND s.date = complete_dates_station.dt
                ORDER by s.station_id, date desc
                LIMIT 1) as s on TRUE
             ORDER BY station_id, dt
         ) SELECT * from temp_join
```

This works like a charm, but this join is really slow for my complete table, which has more than 2M rows and the date range goes over 18 years (I stopped after 4 hrs of running). I tried a simpler approach by using a regular `LEFT JOIN`, but the table outputs the not-joined groups as missings:

```sql
WITH complete_dates_station AS (
    SELECT station_id,
           generate_series(date '2014-01-01', date '2014-12-31', interval '1 day')::date as dt
    from stations
    GROUP BY station_id)
SELECT s.station_id,
       c.dt,
       s.value
FROM complete_dates_station c
    left outer join stations s
    on c.station_id = s.station_id and
    c.dt = s.date;
```

which yields the following:

```
| station | value | date       |
|---------|-------|------------|
| 001     | 10    | 2014-01-01 |
| NULL    | NULL  | 2014-01-02 |
| 001     | 30    | 2014-01-03 |
| NULL    | NULL  | 2014-01-04 |
| 002     | 40    | 2014-01-01 |
| 002     | 50    | 2014-01-02 |
| NULL    | NULL  | 2014-01-03 |
| NULL    | NULL  | 2014-01-04 |
| 003     | 20    | 2014-01-01 |
| 003     | 10    | 2014-01-02 |
| NULL    | NULL  | 2014-01-03 |
| 003     | 70    | 2014-01-04 |
```

There is any way to optimize the first query, or use a simpler approach to fill my `station` gaps in the second query? I tried already using multicolumn indexes in my source table, but the query is still taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have a table holding unique stations with identifiers, Could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE uniq_stations (station_id text);
INSERT INTO uniq_stations VALUES
('001'),
('002'),
('003');
```

There will be more columns, which are irrelevant for us.

This should be *much* faster then:

```
SELECT station_id, s.value, date
FROM   uniq_stations u
CROSS  JOIN (
   SELECT generate_series (timestamp '2014-01-01'
                         , timestamp '2014-01-04'
                         , interval  '1 day')::date
   ) d(date)
LEFT   JOIN stations s USING (station_id, date)
ORDER  BY station_id, date;  -- optional
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c333931175eaea40dcc13c3aa227c272)*

You do not need a `LATERAL` join at all, the date series is the same for every station. Only a `CROSS JOIN` to build the complete Cartesian product of stations and days, then a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to existing combinations in table `stations` (an unfortunate table name for its content, btw.). `LATERAL` joins are great, when needed. But plain joins are faster.

Also, this fills in stations with *all* days missing, which would not work at all without `uniq_stations`. You may or may not have such cases.

One of the expensive pieces in this puzzle is identifying unique stations. A task we can skip completely if we can use the added `uniq_stations` providing what we need. Else we might use `DISTINCT ON` or a recursive CTE to make use of a matching index. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Still more expensive than reading unique rows from a table, but *much* faster already than what you had. Which was a grand waste of CPU cycles, frankly.

Finally, a **[multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html)** on `stations (station_id, date)` should deliver top notch performance even with a big table `stations`. (Using a higher percentage of rows from that table makes the index less important.)

There is a reason I use `generate_series (timestamp, timestamp, interval)`:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499873/939860)

Related:

- [Filling in missing dates in record set from generate_series()](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72419/filling-in-missing-dates-in-record-set-from-generate-series/72620#72620)
- [Join a count query on a generate_series in postgres and also retrieve Null-values as “0”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13414797/939860)

Aside: Your `station_id` should probably type `integer`. Faster than `text`, and smaller, too if numbers go beyond 999.

Comment: About CTEs: It's typically faster to use subqueries instead of CTEs. Only use CTEs where you actually *need* them. This changes with the upcoming Postgres 12 where CTEs can be inlined. Similar for `LATERAL`: use it when you need it. A plain join is typically cheaper.