# Generate multiple running totals with GROUP BY day

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, window-functions, set-returning-functions

I have a set of transactions of stock purchases by users and I want to keep track of a running balance of each stock as the year progresses. I am using a windowing function to track the running balance but for some reason I cannot get the `GROUP BY` portion of this query to work.

It continues to have duplicate days in the result set even when I attempt to group by the date (`created_at`). Sample below:

```
select
  t.customer_id,
  t.created_at::date,
  sum(case when t.stock_ticker = 'tsla' then t.amount end) over (order by t.created_at::date rows unbounded preceding) as tsla_running_amount,
  sum(case when t.stock_ticker = 'goog' then t.amount end) over (order by t.created_at::date rows unbounded preceding) as goog_running_amount,
from transactions t
group by t.created_at, t.customer_id, t.stock_ticker, t.amount
order by t.created_at desc;
```

Test setup:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
   transaction_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   amount float8 NOT NULL,
   stock_ticker varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   transaction_type varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   customer_id varchar NOT NULL,
   inserted_at timestamp NOT NULL,
   created_at timestamp NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT transactions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
);

INSERT INTO transactions(transaction_id, amount, stock_ticker, transaction_type, customer_id, inserted_at, created_at)
VALUES
  ('123123abmk12', 10, 'tsla', 'purchase', 'a1b2c3', '2020-04-01 01:00:00', '2020-04-01 01:00:00')
, ('123123abmk13', 20, 'tsla', 'purchase', 'a1b2c3', '2020-04-03 01:00:00', '2020-04-03 01:00:00')
, ('123123abmk14',  5, 'goog', 'purchase', 'a1b2c3', '2020-04-01 01:00:00', '2020-04-01 01:00:00')
, ('123123abmk15',  8, 'goog', 'purchase', 'a1b2c3', '2020-04-03 01:00:00', '2020-04-03 01:00:00');

CREATE INDEX ix_transactions_customer_id ON transactions USING btree (customer_id);
```

The result here always comes back with multiple rows per day, when I want them to be grouped all into one day.

After doing some research I attempted to cast `created_at` to `date` in the `GROUP BY` clause as well, but I get this error:

> ```
> Column t.created_at must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
> ```

In addition, the results are only going to show days in which a transaction has happened for a user. I need to be able to show a row for each day in a time series (1 year) even if the user did not make a transaction that day. (Using the most recent running balance on the row instead.)

I think that `generate_series()` is the way to go, but I am having trouble understanding how to fit it in.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! So that allows the query to run using t.created_at::date, but it still returns multiple rows per date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of issues. This should do it:

```
SELECT * -- ⑥
FROM   (  -- ①
   SELECT the_day::date
   FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2020-01-01', date_trunc('day', localtimestamp), interval '1 day') the_day
   ) d 
LEFT   JOIN ( -- ②
   SELECT customer_id
        , created_at::date AS the_day -- ⑥
        , sum(sum(t.amount) FILTER (WHERE stock_ticker = 'tsla')) OVER w AS tsla_running_amount -- ③
        , sum(sum(t.amount) FILTER (WHERE stock_ticker = 'goog')) OVER w AS goog_running_amount
   FROM   transactions t
   WHERE  created_at >= timestamp '2020-01-01'  -- ④
   GROUP  BY customer_id, created_at::date  -- ⑤
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY created_at::date) -- ③
   ) t USING (the_day) -- ⑥
ORDER  BY customer_id, the_day; -- ⑦
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=92bf4666227e824c32ec622389436777)*

① Generating all days of the current year in optimized fashion. See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499873/939860)

② The `LEFT JOIN` you had in mind. You may really want one row per combination of `(customer_id, day)`. See:

- [Fill missing dates within groups](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242689/fill-missing-dates-within-groups/242697#242697)

③ While you also `GROUP BY customer_id` the Window frame needs to lead with `PARTITION BY customer_id`.

Drop `rows unbounded preceding`. The default window frame should be just fine. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html)

> The default framing option is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which is the
>   same as `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

Use the aggregate `FILTER` clause instead of the `CASE` expression. Shorter, faster, cleaner. See:

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

Finally wrap the result of the aggregation in another `sum()` for the window function. See:

- [Get the distinct sum of a joined table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13169627/939860)

The separate [`WINDOW` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WINDOW) avoids spelling out the same repeatedly. No effect on performance.

④ The `WHERE` is logically redundant, but assuming there are older rows, too, it excludes irrelevant rows early, improving performance.
  Asuming no or almost no future timestamps, so no upper bound.

⑤ You cannot have `t.stock_ticker, t.amount` in `GROUP BY` as you want one row per `(customer_id, the_day)`.

⑥ Use the same column alias (`the_day` in my example) to allow the simple `USING (the_day)` in the `JOIN` clause, and `SELECT *` at the top level.

⑦ Not sure about the final sort order. This seems more useful to me. Adjust to your preference.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing man. Goes to show how much I still need to learn. The only issue that I had was that if I didn't include t.stock_ticker, and t.account within my GROUP BY, I was getting the same "Column t.amount t.stock_ticker must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" error that I was seeing before. When I include them though it runs. Any idea if this might be causing a data issue by adding them? Again thank you so much for this and the comments, they helped a ton to understand how this all works.

Comment: Following up after testing, definitely looks like as you mentioned it's bringing in mulitple rows because of the additional group by. (Everything else working perfectly). Any idea how I can resolve that error? I think my understanding of what goes on behind the scenes with group by is lacking.

Comment: Is there a way to default value to 0 if null using a Filter? I know how to do with CASE but haven't seen much use of filter before.

Comment: @parchambeau: The outer `sum()` was missing. That's what happens without testing. Fixed and added a fiddle with test case. (Please provide table definition and sample data with your next question.)

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I understand why that sum was needed to satisfy the condition. How would I go about doing this for the solving the problem with "t.stock_picker" still causing the error? I don't have a need of wrapping it in some type of aggregate for this usecase. (I am also editing the original with a CREATE TABLE ddl and sample data now Thanks!)

Comment: Updated with sample create table DDL and sample data. I am trying to get this to work also by having days where there is no transactional information just use the most recent "running balance" for each stock_ticker. (Meaning the previous that was calculated)

Comment: `How would I go about doing this for the solving the problem with "t.stock_picker" ...` Please ask a new question for the new question. This one is dealing with too much at the same time already. (Also, new questions generally go into new questions.) You can always link to this one for context and drop a comment here to link back.

Comment: Perfect, and again thank you so much for the help with this. Huge learning experience for me.

Comment: I updated to your given test setup and added notes on empty rows per customer to round this off.

Comment: New thread: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266009/postgresql-return-previous-running-balance-totals-when-records-null-generate