# Return previous running total when value is null in a time series

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, window-functions, set-returning-functions

This is a continuation of a [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265956/generate-multiple-running-totals-with-group-by-day#265963), where table definition and sample data can be found. (Huge thanks to @Erwin Brandstetter for the help there).

All of this is being done on a PostgreSQL 11.5 DB.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
   SELECT the_day::date
   FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2020-01-01', date_trunc('day', localtimestamp), interval '1 day') the_day
   ) d 
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT customer_id
        , created_at::date AS the_day
        , sum(sum(t.amount) FILTER (WHERE stock_ticker = 'tsla')) OVER w AS tsla_running_amount
        , sum(sum(t.amount) FILTER (WHERE stock_ticker = 'goog')) OVER w AS goog_running_amount
   FROM   transactions t
   WHERE  created_at >= timestamp '2020-01-01'
   GROUP  BY customer_id, created_at::date
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY created_at::date)
   ) t USING (the_day)
ORDER  BY customer_id, the_day;
```

When a customer has NO transactions on a day, I need to be able to display the "most recent" running total for that customer for that day.

For example:

```
2020-01-01: Customer purchases 5 "tsla" for a total balance of 5.
2020-01-02: Customer takes no action. Current total balance display as 5.
2020-01-03: Customer sells 2 "tsla", total balance now 3.
2020-01-04: Customer takes no action. Current balance still display as 3.
```

Currently, the way that this is set up, the record for a customer on a day where they have no transactions will return as a NULL row for balance totals.

**How can I display their "most recent" running balance on days when they have no transactions?**

This query will be running for all customers that exist within the `transactions` table (have had a transaction at least once in the past).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to generate one row per `(customer_id, the_day)` *before* running the window function. Like:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, d.the_day
     , sum(t.tsla_amount) OVER w AS tsla_running_amount
     , sum(t.goog_amount) OVER w AS goog_running_amount
FROM   (
   SELECT the_day::date
   FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2020-01-01'
                        , date_trunc('day', localtimestamp)
                        , interval '1 day') the_day
   ) d 
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id FROM transactions) c  -- !
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT customer_id
        , created_at::date AS the_day
        , sum(t.amount) FILTER (WHERE stock_ticker = 'tsla') AS tsla_amount
        , sum(t.amount) FILTER (WHERE stock_ticker = 'goog') AS goog_amount
   FROM   transactions t
   WHERE  created_at >= timestamp '2020-01-01'
   GROUP  BY customer_id, created_at::date
   ) t USING (customer_id, the_day)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY the_day)
ORDER  BY customer_id, the_day;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1c5ec94690df5d3de9b40f2832c4c097)*

If the table is big, and there are only relatively few distinct customers, you might want to optimize performance. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

But you would typically have a separate table of customers to work with ...

If you want `0` instead of `NULL` in rows before the first transaction of a customer, add [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL). Like:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, d.the_day
     , COALESCE(sum(t.tsla_amount) OVER w, 0) AS tsla_running_amount
     , COALESCE(sum(t.goog_amount) OVER w, 0) AS goog_running_amount
FROM ...
```

Comment: I actually do have a separate table of customers where the customer_id lives as well named "accounts". Can I just join that here instead of the cross join?

Comment: @parchambeau: If it holds exactly one row for every customer of interest, that would be a much faster drop-in replacement. (Still a `CROSS JOIN` to form the Cartesian product.)

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Is there a way to make it faster by not including customers up until the point of their 1st transaction? And then just having them going forward from that point? So like, a customer only shows up on the date of their 1st transaction, and then going forward the running total balance calculates in the same fashion (previous balance showing on day they dont have transactions). I feel like that would cut down the giant cartesian join a lot.

Comment: There are ways. I suggest you put that separate optimization problem in yet another question. Include cardinalities there: number of rows, number of customers, range of possible time series, earliest transaction on avg (roughly). And can the first transaction change later in history?

Comment: Updated: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266018/postgresql-how-do-i-optimize-my-transaction-level-running-balances-cartesian-j