# Backfilling data using generate time series

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, time-series-database

I have a table like this:

| Date | Group name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 1.0 |
| 2022-01-15 | A | 0.5 |
| 2022-01-31 | A | 0.2 |

but this contains only 3 days. I need a table with full-calendar dates, a row for every day of the year where the value is the last available.
For example, all records from 1 Jan 2022 to 14 Jan have value 1.0 (scoped to `group_name` 'A').

I have tried using `LAST_VALUE()` but it's not working.

```
WITH dates AS (
    
    SELECT 
        date::date
    FROM generate_series ( '2022-01-01'::timestamp, '2022-01-31'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) date

), incomplete_table AS (
     SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        ('2022-01-01'::date, 'a', 1),
        ('2022-01-15'::date, 'a', 0.5), 
        ('2022-01-31'::date, 'a', 0.2), 
        ('2022-01-02'::date, 'b', 0.1),
        ('2022-01-10'::date, 'b', 0.15),
        ('2022-01-20'::date, 'b', 0.15)
    ) AS t (date,group_name, value)
)
SELECT
    dates.date,
    group_name, 
    value,
    LAST_VALUE(value) OVER (ORDER BY dates.date DESC) as last_value_window
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN incomplete_table ON incomplete_table.date = dates.date
ORDER BY dates.date DESC;
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you are looking for the query to return? Additionally, considering creating a Fiddle.

Comment: `scoped to group_name A` means you want one row per day and group name? Or fill in `date` *and* `group_name`from the last nonnull value? Independently? Also, please *always* declare your version of Postgres.  Also, an exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) is much better than a CTE, telling us exact data types and constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want one row per day ***and*** group name:

```
WITH incomplete_table(date, group_name, value) AS (
   VALUES 
     ('2022-01-01'::date, 'a', 1)
   , ('2022-01-15'::date, 'a', 0.5)
   , ('2022-01-31'::date, 'a', 0.2)
   , ('2022-01-02'::date, 'b', 0.1)
   , ('2022-01-10'::date, 'b', 0.15)
   , ('2022-01-20'::date, 'b', 0.15)
   )
SELECT d.date, g.group_name, i.value
FROM  (
   SELECT date::date
   FROM   generate_series (timestamp '2022-01-01'
                         , timestamp '2022-01-31'
                         , interval '1 day') date
   ) d
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT group_name FROM incomplete_table) g  -- ①
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT i.group_name, i.value
   FROM   incomplete_table i
   WHERE  i.group_name = g.group_name
   AND    i.date <= d.date
-- AND    i.date >= timestamp '2022-01-01'  -- ? ②
   ORDER  BY i.date DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) i ON true
ORDER  BY g.group_name, d.date DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6a683b65cd480b1c9c934626ed098b77)*

① If available, use a table "groups" providing distinct group names. Faster. Else, if the table is big, consider an emulated index-skip scan. See:

- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66894500/939860)

② The search for the latest value is not limited to the given time range unless you spell that out in the `LATERAL` subquery. About `LATERAL`:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

You still get `value IS NULL` where no earlier value is found.

If `incomplete_table` is big, an **index** on `(group_name, date)` will help performance (a lot). Possibly even a "covering" index, adding column `value`. See:

- [Slow index scans in large table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81456/slow-index-scans-in-large-table/81554#81554)

Very similar case with more explanation:

- [Return previous running total when value is null in a time series](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266009/return-previous-running-total-when-value-is-null-in-a-time-series/266013#266013)