# Filling gaps in result with empty data

Tags: postgresql, join, date

```
PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, 
compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

Hello All,

I'm a bit stuck on this one.

### Working SQL

Currently I am using this query:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('year', created_at::timestamp) AS year,
       DATE_PART('week', created_at::timestamp) AS week_number,
       DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at::timestamp) AS week_starting,
       name,
       SUM(seconds) as total_seconds
FROM my_table
WHERE name = 'jeff'
AND created_at::date >= '2021-01-01'
AND created_at::date <= '2021-10-01'
GROUP BY year, week_number, week_starting, name
ORDER BY name;
```

This gives me:

```
| "year" |"week_number" |    "week_starting"    | "name" | "total_seconds" |
| "2021" |    "18"      | "2021-05-03 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "11"            |
| "2021" |    "19"      | "2021-05-10 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "40"            |  
| "2021" |    "23"      | "2021-06-07 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "7"             |
```

What I would like is a result with the gaps filled in:

```
| "year" |"week_number" |    "week_starting"    | "name" | "total_seconds" |
| "2021" |    "18"      | "2021-05-03 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "11"            |
| "2021" |    "19"      | "2021-05-10 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "40"            |  
| "2021" |    "20"      | "2021-05-17 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "0"             |
| "2021" |    "21"      | "2021-05-24 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "0"             |  
| "2021" |    "22"      | "2021-05-31 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "0"             |  
| "2021" |    "23"      | "2021-06-07 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "7"             |
```

### Setup DB table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    seconds INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO my_table(name, created_at, seconds) VALUES ('jeff', '2021-05-03 15:28', 10);
INSERT INTO my_table(name, created_at, seconds) VALUES ('jeff', '2021-05-03 15:29', 1);
INSERT INTO my_table(name, created_at, seconds) VALUES ('jeff', '2021-05-10 11:01', 20);
INSERT INTO my_table(name, created_at, seconds) VALUES ('jeff', '2021-05-11 13:23', 20);
INSERT INTO my_table(name, created_at, seconds) VALUES ('jeff', '2021-06-08 10:04', 2);
INSERT INTO my_table(name, created_at, seconds) VALUES ('jeff', '2021-06-09 06:27', 5);
```

### What I have tried so far

So there is a lot of posts around about using `GENERATE_SERIES`

- [Fill missing dates within groups](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242689/fill-missing-dates-within-groups)
- https://ubiq.co/database-blog/fill-missing-dates-using-postgresql-generate_series/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100445/adding-missing-date-in-a-table-in-postgresql

And I can create a series of weeks starting using:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', GENERATE_SERIES(
    '2021-01-01'::timestamp,
    '2021-10-01'::timestamp,
    '1 week'::interval
  )) as created_at
```

I have had a good look at using this and in my mind I have tried to create an "empty" weeks temporary table and then merge that into `my_table` to give the desired output of filling the gaps.
However the below query just gives me back the data thats in `my_table` and does not fill the gaps. Can someone explain what am I missing here?

### Working query

```
SELECT empty_weeks.created_at,
       DATE_PART('year', empty_weeks.created_at::timestamp) AS year,
       DATE_PART('week', empty_weeks.created_at::timestamp) AS week_number,
       DATE_TRUNC('week', empty_weeks.created_at::timestamp) AS week_starting,
       t.name,
       SUM(t.seconds) as total_seconds
       
      FROM (
        SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', GENERATE_SERIES(
          '2021-01-01'::timestamp,
          '2021-10-01'::timestamp,
          '1 week'::interval
        )) as created_at,
        'jeff' as name,
        0 as seconds          
      ) empty_weeks
      
      LEFT JOIN my_table t
      ON DATE_TRUNC('week', t.created_at) = empty_weeks.created_at
      
      WHERE t.name = 'jeff'
      AND empty_weeks.created_at::date >= '2021-01-01'
      AND empty_weeks.created_at::date <= '2021-10-01'
      GROUP BY year, week_number, week_starting, empty_weeks.created_at, t.name
      ORDER BY t.name;
```

### Provides

```
| "year" |"week_number" |    "week_starting"    | "name" | "total_seconds" |


| "2021" |    "18"      | "2021-05-03 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "11"            |
| "2021" |    "19"      | "2021-05-10 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "40"            |  
| "2021" |    "23"      | "2021-06-07 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "7"             |
```

### What I would like

```
| "year" |"week_number" |    "week_starting"    | "name" | "total_seconds" |
| "2021" |    "1"       | "2020-12-28 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "0"       
...
| "2021" |    "18"      | "2021-05-03 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "11"            |
| "2021" |    "19"      | "2021-05-10 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "40"            |  
| "2021" |    "20"      | "2021-05-17 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "0"             |
| "2021" |    "21"      | "2021-05-24 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "0"             |  
| "2021" |    "22"      | "2021-05-31 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "0"             |  
| "2021" |    "23"      | "2021-06-07 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "7"             |
...
| "2021" |    "40"      | "2021-09-27 00:00:00" | "jeff" | "0"
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated but also an explanation would be great. I have had a good read up on `LEFT JOIN` and I'm expecting it to provide empty rows of data.

As always thanks in advance

### Solution

For completeness and thanks to @mustaccio I changed the query to:

```
SELECT empty_weeks.created_at,
       DATE_PART('year', empty_weeks.created_at::timestamp) AS year,
       DATE_PART('week', empty_weeks.created_at::timestamp) AS week_number,
       DATE_TRUNC('week', empty_weeks.created_at::timestamp) AS week_starting,
       COALESCE(t.name, 'jeff'),
       COALESCE(SUM(t.seconds), 0) as total_seconds
       
      FROM (
        SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', GENERATE_SERIES(
          '2021-01-01'::timestamp,
          '2021-10-01'::timestamp,
          '1 week'::interval
        )) as created_at      
      ) empty_weeks
      
      LEFT JOIN my_table t
      ON DATE_TRUNC('week', t.created_at) = empty_weeks.created_at
      AND t.name = 'jeff'
      AND empty_weeks.created_at::date >= '2021-01-01'
      AND empty_weeks.created_at::date <= '2021-10-01'
      GROUP BY year, week_number, week_starting, empty_weeks.created_at, t.name
      ORDER BY week_number;
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause effectively turns your left join into an inner join. Move `t.name = 'jeff'` to the join condition.

Comment: And a healthy dose of `COALESCE` gives me the empty values I want

Comment: Are yiou sure that the weeks start bang on the 1st 9f Jan?

Comment: @Vérace this is just example code and I want the start of the week for the queried dates. So Monday 28th of December is correct in this case

Comment: @ZedRed - that's fine - at least you're aware that the year doesn't necessarily start from YYYY-MM-01 - that's the case in many businesses **"ISO-8601 years always start on the first Monday closest to January 1st."**.